# CakePHP hasOne ineffeciency?

Tags: php, cakephp, has-one

I was looking at examples on the CakePHP website, in particular hasOne used in linking models.
http://book.cakephp.org/view/78/Associations-Linking-Models-Together

My question is this, is CakePHP using two queries to build the array structure of data returned in a model that uses hasOne linkage?

Taken from CakePHP:
//Sample results from a $this->User->find() call.

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 121
            [name] => Gwoo the Kungwoo
            [created] => 2007-05-01 10:31:01
        )
    [Profile] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [user_id] => 121
            [skill] => Baking Cakes
            [created] => 2007-05-01 10:31:01
        )
)
```

Hope this all makes sense.

Comment: Can't you just check the SQL log?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have CakePHP so was asking in hopes that someone else with knowledge of CakePHP could provide an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Model::find` uses joins to retrieve model records associated to the source model by `hasOne` and `belongsTo` relationships. The specific SQL queries look something like (using a `Car belongsTo Driver` model structure):

```
SELECT `Car`.`brand`, `Car`.`colour`, `Driver`.`name`, `Driver`.`age`
    FROM `cars` AS `Car`
    LEFT JOIN `drivers` AS `Driver` ON `Car`.`id` = `Driver`.`car_id`
WHERE `Car`.`brand` = 'Aston Martin'
```

The fields belonging to each model can be parsed out into corresponding array elements by the table/model alias:

- `Car.brand` becomes `$result['Car']['brand']`
- `Car.colour` becomes `$result['Car']['colour']`
- `Driver.name` becomes `$result['Driver']['name']`
- `Driver.age` becomes `$result['Driver']['age']`

Only one query required.

Retrieving data for `hasMany` and `hasAndBelongsToMany` associations requires additional queries, sometimes many more.

Comment: Understood.

In the event that find() is used to return all (multiple) users, is the SQL result set iterated over to create an enumerated array containing corresponding array with table/model alias?

In which case does this not add an extra loop?

Comment: Yes, in that scenario, it will loop through every row returned by the query, and through each field of every row, to prepare the array ultimately returned by `Model::find('all')`. You can dig into the documentation for `DboSource::fetchAll` and `DboMysql::fetchResult` (or whatever data-source interests you) for specific details.

Comment: I imagine this may be tough question to answer, but does the extra loop not add a certain amount of inefficiency especially when working with models that have many 'hasMany' and 'hasOne' associations?

Thanks again for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

pretty sure most if not all hasOne and belongsTo are done using join. so one query. you can always set debug to 2 in config.php to see the sql query

Comment: What then of the array structure, can I assume they are indeed using one query, but then iterating over the SQL result set to form this structure?